# DropDown option to show subset of dataframe Tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, dropdown

I have a dataframe pandas of which i want to make GUI to display the data , i have date_time one column which show data every one hour interval i want to make a dropdown option suppose if user select 1 hours then only the 1 hours all columns & rows show , if user select 2 hour then second all columns & rows display . Cany any one please help me how to display the data gving dropdown option. 
I will really Appreciate it. Thanks in Advance.

```
SAMPLE DATA:

Name:   Longitude(degree)   Latitude(degree)    DATE_TIME   Mean Sea Value (m)  DRY or WET
SD      87.0308            21.4441    00:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.0467     DRY
Sea1    87.0544            21.4152    00:00 IST 05-08-2019    -1.0653     DRY
4K      86.9927            21.4197    00:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.1331     DRY
4KP1    86.9960            21.4166    00:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.0863     DRY
Name:   Longitude(degree)   Latitude(degree)    DATE_TIME   Mean Sea Value (m)  DRY or WET
SD      87.0308          21.4441      01:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.0329     DRY
Sea1    87.0544          21.4152      01:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.4067     DRY
4K      86.9927          21.4197      01:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.0897     DRY
4KP1    86.9960           21.4166     01:00 IST 05-08-2019    -0.0676     DRY
```

Comment: create dropdown with options, get value from dropdown and use it in pandas to select rows which you want to display, and then display them. See: [OptionMenu](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm)

Comment: Any Example similar ?
How to pass rows & columns as variable in dropdown ,
I have more than 400 rows with 6 columns .

Comment: in link you have example how to use OptionMenu. Simply get value from OptionMenu and use it with pandas - `df2 = df1[ filter ]` - and then display `df2`. Frankly I don't understand what you want to select. If you want better example then first create minimal working code which we could run and modify.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal example how to use OptionMenu to filter data in `DataFrame`

I will not try to display it in tkinter because it is different problem.

---

I create list with values which I will display in `OptionMenu`

```
values = ['all'] + list(df['TIME'].unique())
```

and variable which I will use to get selection after pressing button

```
selected = tk.StringVar()
```

When I get selection then I can use

```
df2 = df[ filter ]
```

to select only some rows.

---

If you need something different then you have to better describe problem and show some code which can be used to test and modifications.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---

def on_click():
    val = selected.get()
    if val == 'all':
        print(df)
    else:        
        df2 = df[ df['TIME'] == val ]
        print(df2)

# --- main ---

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': ['00:00','00:00','01:00','01:00','02:00','02:00'],
    'A': ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
    'B': ['x','x','y','y','z','z'],
})

root = tk.Tk()

values = ['all'] + list(df['TIME'].unique())
selected = tk.StringVar()

options = tk.OptionMenu(root, selected, *values)
options.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** version with data displayed in `GUI` - not ideal but it shows all or filtered data.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---

def showdata():
    global table

    # destroy old frame with table
    if table:
        table.destroy()

    # create new frame with table         
    table = tk.Frame(frame_data)
    table.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # fill frame with table
    row, column = df2.shape
    for r in range(row):
        for c in range(column):
            e1 = tk.Entry(table)
            e1.insert(1, df2.iloc[r, c])
            e1.grid(row=r, column=c, padx=2, pady=2)
            e1.config(state='disabled')

def on_click():
    global df2

    val = selected.get()

    if val == 'all':
        df2 = df
        #next_button.grid_forget()
    else:
        df2 = df[ df['TIME'] == val ]
        #next_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

    print(df2)
    showdata()
    next_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

# --- main ---

frame_data = None

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'TIME': ['00:00','00:00','01:00','01:00','02:00','02:00'],
    'A': ['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
    'B': ['x','x','y','y','z','z'],
})

root = tk.Tk()

values = ['all'] + list(df['TIME'].unique())
selected = tk.StringVar()

options = tk.OptionMenu(root, selected, *values)
options.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='OK', command=on_click)
button.pack()

# frame for table and button "Next Data"
frame_data = tk.Frame(root)
frame_data.pack()

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="EXIT", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack() 

# table with data - inside "frame_data" - without showing it
table = tk.Frame(frame_data)
#table.grid(row=0, column=0)

# buttom "Next Data" - inside "frame_data" - without showing it
next_button = tk.Button(frame_data, text="Next Data", command=showdata)
#next_button.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much , i really appreciate your help ,
But i want the all rows & columns data to show when we select time 00 in dropdown then it display all the rows & columns data of 00 time ,
Please let me know how to proceed that , rows & columns of 00 time can be in entery or label any . 
Thank you.

Comment: but my example do this. when you select time `01:00` then it display (`print()`) all rows & columns which have time `01:00`

Comment: Actually i want to see the data on GUI not on terminal ,
For that my try is below which is giving error in Entry 
**_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-row": must be -after, -anchor, -before, -expand, -fill, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, or -side** using Entry

Comment: else:
        df2 = df[ df['TIME'] == val ]
        print(df2)
        row, column = df.shape
        for r in range(row):

            for c in range(column):
                e1 = tk.Entry(root)
                e1.insert(1, df.iloc[r, c])
                e1.pack(row=r, column=c)
                e1.config(state='disabled')

Comment: as I wrote in answer: displaying in GUI is different big problem.

Comment: there are different layout managers - `pack()`, `grid()`, `place()`. And `grid()` use `"row"` but `pack()`,  `place()` don't use `"row"`

Comment: BTW: you should create function which get dataframe and create table with `Entry` - this way you could run it with different dataframes - full dataframe or filtered.

Comment: I added example which display data in GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your code furas. I want to display different data frames each time when the user selects Dataframe name on options menu..Dataframes are stored in dictionary.But when I used the above code for my purpose , I am getting name error:NameError: name 'df2' is not defined

Comment: better create question on new page and add all information and minimal working code with your problem. Are you use global variable `df2` ? Did you define `df2` at start with some value?